# Remove whitespace under area chart

Tags: apexcharts

[image]
This is my options:

```js
xaxis: {
    labels: {
      show: false
    },
    crosshairs: {
      show: false,
    },
    axisBorder: {
      show: false
    },
    axisTicks: {
      show: false,
    },
    tooltip: {
      enabled: false
    }
},
grid: {
    show: false,
    padding: {
      top: -30,
      bottom: 0,
      left: -10,
      right: 0
    },
},
```

I don't know how to remove this whitespace. I have parent div with fixed 300px height.
I tryed to remove xaxis labels, border, ticks, tooltip. But it seems like there is something more.
Can somebody help me with this issue?

The grid padding top and bottom does not help with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found a solution.
Set `chart.sparkline.enabled` to `false`